# How to set path for tornado server

Tags: python, server, tornado

I'm building a server with python tornado. My colleague has finished the frontend part.

I've done a very simple test as below:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            print("this is a get request from indexhandler:\n")
            print(self.request)
            self.render("frontend/index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

For this test, the browser get `500: Internal Server Error`. Because the `index.html` contains some js files in sub directories.
Here is the messages of the server:

> [I 170430 23:06:21 web:2063] 200 GET / (108.61.177.156) 2.56ms
>   [W 170430 23:06:22 web:2063] 404 GET /css/reset.css (108.61.177.156) 0.56ms
>   [W 170430 23:06:22 web:2063] 404 GET /css/common.css (108.61.177.156) 0.56ms
>   [W 170430 23:06:22 web:2063] 404 GET /css/index.css (108.61.177.156) 0.41ms

It means that the browser got the `index.html` but couldn't get those `css` files.

So i'm thinking that I need to do something like this:

```
self.render("frontend/*")
```

I've tried like this but failed.

Also, if I do need some kind of regular expression to do this, I think it's very dangerous, because user could do such a request from his browser:

> www.mysite.com/../../someLocalFileOfServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the document of tornado? Just check this document for static serving.
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#static-files-and-aggressive-file-caching

### Update

why will it be dangerous? Suppose you have a project like this:

```
project
--static_dir
----test.js
----some other static files
--view
----index.html
----some other view files
--server.py
```

you can set your `static dir` to static_dir, and then the user will have access to `test.js` by url `domian/test.js`. So what the user has access to is decided by you.

Comment: So I have to fix all of resources? Is there some dynamic way?

Comment: @Yves you need to adjust your structure of project. Create a dir for all the static files.